# TCL : what '*' and '-' indicates in the format command

Tags: tcl

```
% format "| %-*s | %-*s |" 2 "Index" 10 "Power"
| Index | Power      |
%
```

Here in my case , I know that  '-' tells the interpreter right padding.

But what '*' indicates here ?

Answer (score 3):

Take the next argument and use it as the field width.

For the first field in your example `10`, for the 2nd and 3rd field there is no further argument.

The `-` is irrelevant. It causes the field to be left-justified. But this is already the default for strings (`s`).

From the [documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm#M14):

> #### OPTIONAL PRECISION/BOUND
>
> The fourth portion of a conversion specifier is a precision, which consists of a period followed by a number. The number is used in different ways for different conversions. For `e`, `E`, and `f` conversions it specifies the number of digits to appear to the right of the decimal point. For `g` and `G` conversions it specifies the total number of digits to appear, including those on both sides of the decimal point (however, trailing zeroes after the decimal point will still be omitted unless the `#` flag has been specified). For integer conversions, it specifies a minimum number of digits to print (leading zeroes will be added if necessary). For `s` conversions it specifies the maximum number of characters to be printed; if the string is longer than this then the trailing characters will be dropped. **If the precision is specified with `*` rather than a number then the next argument to the format command determines the precision; it must be a numeric string.**

Comment: Everything fine here , i am confused with # flag . Could you please explain that briefly ?

Comment: @user2720323 It means “use alternate form”, which is fully defined further up that page (like, a couple of paragraphs higher). It's only used really rarely; I can't remember ever seeing it in practice, and I've _never_ needed it.

Comment: @DonalFellows I think it is only useful with `g` if you want to show that you get this precision in sientific applications - where the displayed precision tells you something about the calculated precision - don't use 300000000 to display the speed of light, use `%#.3g` to display it.